# Why does $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ need $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$ but only differentiable on $(a,b)$, in some theorems.

Tags: real-analysis

Why in some theorems relating to a real function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ do we need $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$ but only require differentiability on $(a,b)$?

One such example would be Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Do you want an explanation for every theorem of this sort in existence, or just Rolle's theorem? In any case, simply read the proof of said theorem...

Comment: Well I see in Rolle's it is because the function attains it's bounds and so you don't actually need to consider the derivative at the end points in the proof but I don't see it in other cases.

Comment: The statements give the minimal condition necessary to proof the theorems..

Comment: I think I get it now actually, because you can say that the derivative is zero at some point in $(a,b)$ (otherwise you get a contradiction) then you only require that it is differentiable in this interval so we are only concered with this interval.

Comment: @ToTo10 Yeah I realise now just needed to sit there and prove it myself to see how it all worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what mean to be differentiable in closed interval? Think for example that the limits aren't well defined on both sides.